# Maintain the media files after build with Docker Container - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker

I am using Django as a Web Framework. Azure NGINEX as WebServer. My Project is deployed with Docker Containers.

In my Django project root structure will be as follows:

```
root:
  - app1
  - app2
  - media
```

whenever saving images, it will correctly save under media folder. But whenever doing "docker-compose up" it will replaces the source code, so that my media folder will be cleaned up everytime.

In my settings.py file, I have added as follows:

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
 MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

Kindly help me to maintain the media files with Docker based Environment

Comment: you need to use volumes in your compose and remove the copy of the media files if there is one in youe dockerfile

Comment: Please also share your compose file etc so one can provide with more concrete answer - regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer, this isn't a best practice to handle media and static inside your project or app directory rather you can use a file or file storage server. But I am trying to give the answer to your question here.

Suppose you have a Django project directory named `root` and inside this, you are managing the `media` and `static` folders. As you are using `Docker` every time your container gets restarted, it wipes out the contents from both these folders. So what you have to do here is mount your `media` and `static` folders from inside of your container to your local storage i.e `/var/lib/docker/volumes/{volume_name}/_data` to persist your media and static files in between restarts of your container.

I am describing here the `docker-compose` version:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
   app:
     image: {your django project image}
    #build: {direct build of your Dockerfile}
     volumes:
       - media:/src/media/
       - static:/src/static/

volumes:
  media:
  static:
```

My goal here is to point out `volume mount`, so in the above code, you have to define volumes this way, where `/src` is the working directory defined in your `Dockerfile` using the `WORKDIR` directive. And in my case `media and static` are the direct children of the `src` folder. Now you can run `docker volume ls` to see your volume names and using the name you can inspect your volumes using this command `docker volume inspect {volume_name}`. Usually, you will find your volumes i.e media and static here -

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/{{container_name]_media}/_data
/var/lib/docker/volumes/{{container_name]_static}/_data
```

Hope this clears the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to basically do 2 things:

- Changing the directory to keep the media files to somewhere out of your source code directory - it's not any good practice to keep them in the source directory because of several reasons,
- Using docker volumes in your `docker-compose` configuration file to persist your media directory. You can find the detailed documentation on the way to configure volumes in `docker-compose` [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference).

Comment: Your provided comment isn't useful at all

Comment: Do you mean the answer? I appreciate if you improve it or post another answer. May be more details on the docker-compose configuration would help.

Comment: I was expecting exact answer for the question