# Docker is not saving django media files into project 'media' directory on production

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

**App Description**

---

I have an app with django-gunicorn for back-end and reactjs-nginx with front-end all containerized as well as hosted on aws ec2 instance.

**Problem**

---

On development environment, media files are being saved in the 'media' directory permanently. Tho, those files are only saved on the current running docker container on production time. As a result, the files will be removed when I rebuild/stopped the container for a new code push.

**Expectation**

---

I wanted to store the file on the 'media' folder for permanent use.

**Important code**

---

****settings.py****

```
ENV_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'django_static'
STATIC_URL = '/django_static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

****docker-compose-production.yml****

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    db:
       image: postgres
       restart: always #Prevent postgres from stopping the container
        volumes:
               - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
                 - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
                 - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
                 - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
        - 5432:5432

nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
    volumes:
        - static_volume:/code/backend/server/django_static
        - ./docker/nginx/production:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ./docker/nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./docker/nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
        - backend

# Volume for certificate renewal
certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - ./docker/nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./docker/nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
backend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile

    entrypoint: /code/docker/backend/wsgi-entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
        - .:/code
        - static_volume:/code/backend/server/django_static
    expose:
        - 8000
    depends_on:
        -   db

volumes:
       static_volume: { }
       pgdata: { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. I forgot to add .:/code to my nginx volumes config in my docker-compose file.  [Thank to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58555487/15584536)

### Updated nginx volumes confi

```
        volumes:
        - .:/code
        - static_volume:/code/backend/server/django_static
        - ./docker/nginx/production:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ./docker/nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./docker/nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```