# Docker - Media volume not storing data

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, media

I have a Django project in which I have a `media` volume that contains all the files that are uploaded. Some of those files are the instances of a `Script` model. However, there must be something in my definition/use of the volume as I get a `No such file or directory: 'path_of_the_file'` error when trying to access to my files.

I tried different approaches, and discovered that when creating a `Script` instance through the admin panel, the file was accessible until the container's next restart.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-alpine
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - main

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    env_file:
      - env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=Scripts Application
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    env_file:
      - env
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - main

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn
    networks:
      - main

  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A main worker -P eventlet -c 100 -l INFO
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
      - django_gunicorn
      - postgres
    networks:
      - main

networks:
  main:

volumes:
  postgresql-data:
  static:
  media:
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong, so I'd be glad if someone could guide me, thank you in advance !

Comment: Do you store your static and media folder in base directory of your container? Because if it's in another folder, like app, then you should do /app/static and /app/media

Comment: It's in the same folder as my static folder, and I have no problem accessing it so I don't think that comes from there

Comment: What path has Script instance created by admin?

Comment: If I add a Script named `hello_world.py` then its path when created on admin is `media/scripts/hello_world.py`

Comment: And absolute path is /media/scripts/hello_world.py?

Comment: Yes, I've now found the issue, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655075/docker-is-not-saving-django-media-files-into-project-media-directory-on-produc), even though I'm still in the process of understanding what it changes and why it works..thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you add answer containing solution or mark your question as duplicate of that question you metnioned?